# Android - Deep Linking with similar URLs

Tags: android, deep-linking

I'm deep linking (using jetpack navigation) and the logic appears to be working.  The problem I'm running into is the logic for **activity_discover_detail** appears to be blocking the logic for **fragment_discover_landing**

How would I stop that from happening?

Here's the activity and fragment in question from my nav graph:

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_discover_landing"
        android:name="com.my.app.fragments.DiscoverLandingFragment"
        android:label="@string/nav_discover_landing"
        tools:layout="@layout/discover_landing_fragment">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/fragment_discover_landing_back_action"
            app:popUpTo="@id/fragment_reading_lists"
            app:popUpToInclusive="false" />
        <argument
            android:name="category"
            android:defaultValue="Latest"
            app:argType="string" />
        <argument
            android:name="searchText"
            app:argType="string" />
        <argument
            android:name="searchMode"
            android:defaultValue="false"
            app:argType="boolean" />
        <deepLink
            android:id="@+id/discover_landing_category"
            app:uri="myAppName://discover/category?name={category}" />
    </fragment>

    <activity
        android:id="@+id/activity_discover_detail"
        android:name="com.my.app.activities.DiscoverDetailActivity"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_discover_detail">

        <argument
            android:name="already_handled"
            android:defaultValue="true"
            app:argType="boolean" />
        <deepLink
            android:id="@+id/in_app_sell_page"
            app:uri="myAppName://discover/{contentId}" />
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is happening because `myAppName://discover/{contentId}` is more general and contains `myAppName://discover/category?name={category}`.

In general you need to make your activity "handle" more specific in order to not shadow the fragment one.

maybe a link like this one would do the trick : `myAppName://discover/detail/{contentId}`

Also i'm not familiar with the new Navigation Component deep linking,
but i don't see in your code where you define the variable `contentId` what is defined within `DiscoverDetailActivity` scope is `already_handled`, i don't know if that's normal.

**EDIT**

If you don't have control over the link formats, i'd suggest having a single entry point for deeplinks in your nav graph, than doing the proper parsing, mapping, redirection.
it would be a transparent activity `LinkDispatcherActivity` that intercepts all your app links, you can use `.*` wildcard to define your links : This `<deepLink app:uri="myAppHost://myAppScheme/.*"/>` would match and intercept all links starting with `myAppHost://myAppScheme`.

Comment: good eye :) . it's not there yet.  testing the deep link at the moment and haven't finished putting in the arguments.  the "already_handled" bit is a remnant of old code that is in the process of being refactored out

Comment: It WOULD work, for sure... but I have to see if the backend team can and is willing to change their push destinations

Comment: as of now, finding a way to handle it in-app is still the priority